# handling applet exceptions in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

My webapp uses a Java applet whose methods can throw exceptions. A typical method of the applet is shown below.

```
public boolean doSomething() throws PrivilegedActionException {
    return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public Boolean run() throws PrivilegedActionException {

            try {
                // impl omitted
            } catch (SomeException e) {
                throw new CustomException(e, "someErrorCode");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The exception class thrown from the applet looks like this

```
public class CustomException extends PrivilegedActionException {
    String errorCode;

    public CustomException(Throwable t, String errorCode) {
        super(t);
        this.errorCode = errorCode
    }
}
```

When this applet method is invoked from JavaScript, if an exception is thrown I need to retrieve the `errorCode` property

```
try {
     document.myApplet.doSomething();
} catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
}
```

However, if I inspect `err` it appears to be a `String` that indicates the name of the exception class. I was expecting it to be an instance of `Error` and hoping to be able to retrieve the exception's `errorCode` using `err.errorCode`.

How exactly are exceptions thrown from applets converted to JavaScript objects, and is it possible to get more detail than just the name of the exception class?

Comment: Perhaps you should intercept all exceptions in your applet toplevel, and communicate error status and errors through some other means than actual Javascript exceptions. Something like `applet.hasErrorOccurred() and applet.getErrorMessage()`?